# Simple regex for .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a regular expression for a framework to convert `host.com/controller/method` in to `host.com/index.php?controller/method`

Like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I now require it to convert into this,
`host.com/controller/method` -> `host.com/index.php?controller=$1&method=$2`

How would I do a match with a regular expression like so within htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. I will accept because it made the most sense to me quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one path segment instead of just anything, use `[^/]` instead of `.`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And for your second requirement:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Here you should also consider to use the quantifier `+` (one or more) instead of `*` (zero or more).

Comment: I don't think first is a requirement. it seems it works just fine for OP.

Comment: Thank you Gumbo. I will look on to this.